# How to block subscription owner from seeing keyvault values

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In Azure, We are using privileged identity manager for a lot of devops activities, and allow subscription owner access for some people.  However, any owner can add themselves to keyvault access policies and look up all the values.  Is there a way to block this access without putting the keyvault in another subscription?

Comment: Take a look I hope you would get your proper idea about. Still if you have any question feel free to ask here in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you could not do that. This is by design, the `Owner` role will be able to manage everything under the subscription, including access to resources.

Access to a key vault is controlled through two interfaces: the management plane and the data plane.

As mentioned in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault#management-plane-and-rbac):

> If a user has `Contributor` permissions to a key vault management plane, the user can grant themselves access to the data plane by setting a Key Vault access policy. You should tightly control who has `Contributor` role access to your key vaults. Ensure that only authorized persons can access and manage your key vaults, keys, secrets, and certificates.

The permissions of `Owner` is more than `Contributor`, so it is the same logic.

For more details, see this article, it is clear enough:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault. You can also see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) for the built-in roles along with their permissions.